# Can the affdex SDK be used for eye tracking?

Tags: affdex-sdk, eye-tracking

I want to track the positions of eye balls in every frame (eye tracking) using affdex. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Affdex SDK does not perform eye tracking.
here's a list of what it does track:
https://developer.affectiva.com/metrics/

Comment: In Facial Landmarks Estimation (in the link you provided), there are outer left eye, inner right eye, inner left eye, outer right eye. Can these be used in eye tracking? https://knowledge.affectiva.com/v3.2/docs/facial-landmarks-1

Comment: Those landmark describe the positions of the contour of the eyes not the eye balls so you cannot use them in eye tracking.